# Fixing an element size and adding ScrollView on that

Tags: android, ios, react-native, scrollview

I want to add some more information on the bottom of the page and fix this bottom card portion on this page.But on scrolling i want to view the other informations i want to add at the bottom which will only be shown after scrolling.How can i do that?

[image]

I am having this code for now:

```js
 render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style={styles.mapcontainer}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }} />
        <JobInfo/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  mapcontainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: width,
    height: height
  }
})
```

```js
class JobInfo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{width: '100%'}}>
        <Card>
          <CardItem >
            <Text>General Info:</Text>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem >
            <Body>
              <Text>
                Click on any carditem
              </Text>
            </Body>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem >
            <Text>Packaging Info:</Text>
          </CardItem>
            <CardItem >
                <Body>
                  <Text>
                    Click on any carditem
                  </Text>
                </Body>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem >
              <Text>Manpower Info:</Text>
            </CardItem>
              <CardItem >
                  <Body>
                    <Text>
                      Click on any carditem
                    </Text>
                  </Body>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

ScrollView is somehow not working.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: You can use a FlatList or SectionList, and pass your CardItem component to `renderItem` function

Comment: When i  am using FlatList, it just shows the map.Nothing else. @AadityaThakkar

Comment: you want to scroll JobInfo items only.? or Map and Jobinfo together

Comment: just the JobInfo items @VinayakB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below method

add `JobInfo` into a  `Scrollview` . and remove height prop from `mapContainer`

```
 <ScrollView style={[{flex:1} ,{ width: '100%'},  {justifyContent: 'flex-start'}]}>
    <JobInfo/>
    </ScrollView>
```

And `mapContainer` is

```
    mapcontainer: {
    flex: 3,
    width: '100%',
  }
```

Use `flex` values to adjust height of the map

> Edit 1

If you want scroll all container (both Map & JobInfo ) you need to set specific height for Map. Wrap all elements to a single ScrollView like below

```
<ScrollView style={[{flex:1} ,  {justifyContent: 'flex-start'}]}>
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style={styles.mapcontainer}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }} />
        <JobInfo/>
      </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

And styles are follows

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {
     flex: 1,
  },
  mapcontainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height:600,
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes this works.Thanks.But now i realized that i need to scroll the map too. Can you tell me how can i do that? @Vinayak B

Comment: please clarify. is there any content after  <JobInfo/> . if not, then is Map in fixed size(without  flex) ?

Comment: No there is no content after <JobInfo/> and Map is not in fixed size. @Vinayak B

Comment: In that case there is nothing to scroll in map.If I am wrong please correct me. Do you want increase the height of the map. so both top and bottom part of the screen can be scrollable?

Comment: Exactly, when i scroll the JobInfo part i want to scroll the map also. Because now scrolling the JobInfo part is going under the map on scrolling.I want to scroll both. Does that make sense? @Vinayak B

Comment: The height in mapContainer is not working i guess. Thats why the <JobInfo/> part is out of the screen now. I can see that by scrolling on emulator but when on device the scrolling doesn't bring the JobInfo up because it keeps scrolling the map itself and the JobInfo part is out of the screen which i cannot access. Hope i described the issue correctly. @Vinayak B

Comment: in that case you need calculate exact height for your map container.
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
height=height/3


 mapcontainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height:height,
  }
this will useful for you